# Using FOR statement and being able to collect data to the left of variable value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking at my CSV sheet for a check (from my checking account) to compare with another sheet called checking. I want to match checks up. I'm balancing the bank statement. "A" is the value but I also want to store the values to the left of this (the description.) 
I used a double nested "FOR" statement to accomplish this, with the first "FOR" shown here. In the CSV list, the first one is:
Description= Citgo
A=  1.53
next is:
Description = MCD
A = 2.42

When I run the below I get 
a= 1.53
Description: Citgo
Then, as the FOR loops I get:
A=2.42
Description = Citgo (it should be MCD - it's not incrementing.)
How do I correct this?

```
Sheets("CSV").Select
    Set ShtCSV = ActiveSheet
   Range("a499").End(xlUp).Select
Set CSVBottomLeft_A = Selection

Range("d150").End(xlUp).Select
Set CSVBottomRight_D = Selection
    Range("d2", CSVBottomRight_D).Select
Set CSVSelection_Area = Selection
'Range("A1").Select


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sheets("matrix").Select
    Set ShtMx = ActiveSheet
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sheets("checking").Select
    Set ShtChecking = ActiveSheet

       Range("e499").End(xlUp).Select
         BottomChecks_E = Selection.Address
    Set CheckArea = Range("E5", BottomChecks_E)

        Range("d499").End(xlUp).Select
   BottomDeposites_D = Selection.Address
    Set DepositeArea = Range("d5", BottomDeposites_D)

         Range("c499").End(xlUp).Select
            ML 1
    Set BottomLeft_B = Selection

        Range("g499").End(xlUp).Select
    Set BottomRight_G = Selection

        Range("B5", BottomRight_G).Select
    Set CheckSelection_Area = Selection

ShtCSV.Select

For Each A In CSVSelection_Area 'For-1
ShtCSV.Select
    CSV = A
    CSVDescription = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).value 'left 1
    CSVChkNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).value
    CSVDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).value
MsgBox A
MsgBox CSVDescription
next
```

Comment: At the end of your code, change `ActiveCell` to `A`

Comment: That worked @braX ! THANKS! This is going to simplify things considerably!

Answer (score 0):

Using `ActiveCell` refers to the `ActiveWorkSheet` whereas you want to refer to your `A` `Range`. Try it like this instead

```
CSVDescription = A.Offset(0, -1).value 'left 1
CSVChkNumber = A.Offset(0, -2).value
CSVDate = A.Offset(0, -3).value
```